# Cloning a Wordpress Woo Commerce Site with a custom theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have done some research and found some plugins like [duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) that allow you to copy everything, however I'm not sure if it can do what I need.

I have a client who has an existing Wordpress Site that was built using a custom theme and Woo Commerce plugin. They want to copy the website entirely (theme, plugins, database, etc), but just change the content and sell other products. Would it be possible to copy the existing website in its entirety and just change the products in the shop and the content on the web pages?

If you have any good tutorials or resources I would appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You hardly need a tutorial, this is a standard case of "deploying a backup to a new location". Here's the <kbd>[Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)</kbd> Codex entry. I'd give it a read.

Barring the manual process, literally any of the dozens of backup plugins, including [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) will aid you here. Personally we use iThemes' [BackupBuddy](https://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/). There's some script only ones as well like [WP Twin](http://wptwin.com).

All you have to do is use one of the plugins, step by step, and then on the cloned copy, start adding/removing products like you would on any other WordPress site.